# How to link items in TOC using beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, hyperref

I am preparing a fairly straight forward presentation using beamer. My question is this--how do I link items in my table of contents to the appropriate section/subsection? I feel as if there is something simple I'm missing...then again, maybe not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`beamer` documentclass](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/) works in a very similar way to regular LaTeX documentclasses. Moreover, it *necessarily* includes the use of the [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). That is, compiling even this minimal example (taken from the [`beamer` documentclass documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf))

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% This is the file main.tex
\usetheme{Berlin}
\title{Example Presentation Created with the Beamer Package}
\author{Till Tantau}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section*{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Overview of the Beamer Class}
\subsection{Overview of Similar Classes}
\section{Usage}
\subsection{...}
\subsection{...}
\section{Examples}
\subsection{...}
\subsection{...}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} % to enforce entries in the table of contents
\end{document}
```

produces a hyperlinked table of contents. Furthermore, some notable extracts from the documentation includes:

> The empty frame at the end (which should be deleted later) ensures
>   that the sections and subsections are actually part of the table of
>   contents. This frame is necessary since a `\section` or `\subsection`
>   command following the last page of a document has no effect. (Section
>   4.2 *Step Two: Structure Your Presentation*, p 29)

This implies that there is a requirement to use `\frame{...}` or `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` is necessary for the correct setup of your presentation. It may be that you do not have proper frames set up, causing a problem with hyperlinks between your table of contents and sectional headings.

> You can structure your text using the commands `\section` and
>   `\subsection`. Unlike standard LATEX, these commands will not create a
>   heading at the position where you use them. Rather, they will add an
>   entry to the table of contents and also to the navigation bars.
>   (Section 10.2 *Adding Sections and Subsections*, p 95)

With the proper setup, `\section` and `\subsection` commands should link to the table of contents.